# How do you clear the RecordStore of your midlet in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, midlet, rms

I find that when I try to add some new records, the already exist in the recordstore of the midlet, but I don't know where do I find the option to clear the midlet's recordstore in its emulator.

[image]

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps for clear the RMS in your netbeans project,

- Select the **Tools** and go to **Java Platforms.**
- Select **Sun Java(TM) Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 for CLDC** under J2ME.
- Select the **Tools & Extensions** tab and click the **Open Utilities**.
- One **Utilities** Popup will appear on the screen and launch the **Clean Database.** Then press OK button.

This is way to clear the RMS using Netbeans IDE. Also you can delete manually on following workspace,

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Username\j2mewtk\2.5.2\appdb\DefaultColorPhone
```

Delete Database files on above path.