# j2me - Delete record store (RMS) files before starting a MIDlet on Netbeans Emulator

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation, rms

Please does anyone of you know how to clear the RecordStore in the NetBeans Emulator??
I found this [How do you clear the RecordStore of your midlet in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977331/how-do-you-clear-the-recordstore-of-your-midlet-in-netbeans)  , but the solution in that post suggests using an option that it is not available in the version I'm using (netbeans-7.1.1 and jdk-6u23)

[image]

The strange thing about this is that when I installed this very same version on my pc at work and at home it works as expected, that is , every time I run an application RMS is clear, but now that it's time for QA to test my application I give them **the same installers I used**, but the emulator they have keep the RMS even if I close the emulator. Perhaps this is a configuration thing. To be honest I don't understand what might be happening because as I told you I've already installed this emulator in up to 4 computers with the only difference that in those four computers where the emulator works as expected I have also installed the Nokia sdk (S40_6th). I didn't give them also the nokia installer because I don't use it.

Now three people need to test my app at the same time and we only have one physical device,the one I used for development, the other two will have to use the emulator. The problem is that RMS won't be clear no matter what I do.

Your comments and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. This question is a bit dated so I want to ask here: did you find the answer? If not I know how to delete the RMS and can answer it here

Comment: Hi @Fenix. If you know that answer I think you should posted it so anyone having the same problem could find the solution. For me reinstalling the emulator was enough. After that, much to my surprise, it worked as expected. But that obviously is not the best solution.

Comment: Alright ~ will write up tommorow